# Supervisord 3.0a8 on debian ignores child logging options

Tags: unix

I tried tried to configure the logging for supervisor child processes (http://supervisord.org/logging.html).

Here's my config:

```
[program:Test_Prog]
command= /usr/bin/php TestProg.php
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=2
directory=/home/blubb/phpstuff/
autorestart=true
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=test_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
```

The log files still look like

```
Test_Progls_00-stderr---supervisor-ErTqph.log
```

It's not using the pattern from above. As explained in the documentation, if you're not using "stdout_logfile" it generates temp-files. So someone may can help me with that or have an idea. Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S.: I'm using supervisor in version 3.0a8-1 (from debian repository). The documentation is for 3.0a12 and I don't find one from an older version.